# How to manage Android app in datawind app store

Tags: android, app-store, google-play-services

We have a app in Google play store. But how to manage app in datawind app store its like Google play store for Aakash (tablet) in india in which we cannot find 
Google play store. How can we manage updates in this app store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Apptoide](https://datawind-apps.store.aptoide.com/). It's a 3rd party application market. You can find most of the apps which is availble in playstore. For more details visit https://www.aptoide.com/?lang=en.

Also, you may [install Google Play Store](https://www.androidpit.com/forum/589877/how-to-install-google-play-store-if-it-is-not-pre-installed) if it is not pre-installed. This method requires root access.

> Download a couple of APKs, you can usually find the newest bundle in a zip package on [XDA Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2547054):
>
> - Google Play Store (the newest version you can find)
> - Google Services Framework
> - Google Login Service/Account Manager
>
> If you are rooted you can copy them to your root directory to System/App using a root manager like ES File Explorer. Then just restart your device.